# Erro ao ocultar linha do dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Olá, estou precisando ocultar todas as linhas do `dataGridView` que contenham na coluna `data`, a data inferior à data atual, ou seja, com o código abaixo eu recebo o seguinte erro: `Não é possível tornar invisível a linha associada à posição do gerenciador de moeda.`

Código:

```
private void dgvDados_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dgvDados.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        DateTime DataViagem = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvDados.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["data"].Value.ToString());
        DateTime DataAtual = DateTime.Now.Date;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDados.Rows)
        {
            if (DataViagem <= DataAtual)
            {
                row.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Já experimentou colocar um `dgvDados.ClearSelection()` antes de ocultar as linhas?

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano, a linha a qual o cursor aponta não pode ser ocultada,
tente ignorar a linha selecionada do seu datagrid e ocultar as outras.

tenho o seguinte cógido:
Coloquei um checkbox no datagrid, na posição 0 da célula;

Esse código verifica se o checkbox está selecionado e então oculta a linha.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtClientesDtgv.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ck = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
    //Passa se o checkBox estiver selecionado;
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(ck.Value) == true)
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Realmente acredito que o problema seja ocultar a CurrentRow do datagrid.

Comment: Tentei `dgvDados.CurrentCell = null;` mas também não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Julgo que o comando que estas a usar so funciona para a coluna,

```
dataGridView.Columns[4].Visible = false; //isto funciona
dataGridView.row[4].Visible = false; //isto vai dar erro
```

No caso da linha, teras q a retirar a linha da datagridview se nao quiseres q ela apareça

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução que me parece a mais correta para evitar esse problema.
O erro acontece porque existe uma CurrencyManager associada ao DataSource.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    // ****************
    CurrencyManager cm;
    // ****************

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DataTable dt = Modulos.ExecutaQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUTO"))
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            // **********
            cm = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGriView1.DataSource];
            //  *********
        }
    }

    private void OcultaLinha(DataGridViewRow r) 
    {
        // ****************************
        cm.SuspendBinding();
        r.Visible = false;
        cm.ResumeBinding();
        // ****************************
    }
}
```